# Visual C++ chart grid control- set square grid and set axes x and y on the center (0,0)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, charts

I use System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart and .NET Framework 4. My chart looks like this: [current look](http://www.imagebam.com/image/bdcb78342469667).

And my idea ​​how it should look like is this:

So basically I need this: [ideal appearance](http://www.imagebam.com/image/798993342469668).

- change the scale of the grid that has always been the same on the X
  and Y (ie a square grid)
- move the black axis so that they be will
  always at the beginning of the coordinate

Here is code:

```
#pragma once

namespace ChartTest {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart^  chart1;
    protected: 

    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartArea^  chartArea1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartArea());
            System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Legend^  legend1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Legend());
            System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series^  series1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series());
            this->chart1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->chart1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // chart1
            // 
            chartArea1->AxisX->MajorGrid->LineColor = System::Drawing::Color::Gray;
            chartArea1->AxisX->MajorGrid->LineDashStyle = System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartDashStyle::Dash;
            chartArea1->AxisX2->LineDashStyle = System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartDashStyle::NotSet;
            chartArea1->AxisY->MajorGrid->LineColor = System::Drawing::Color::Gray;
            chartArea1->AxisY->MajorGrid->LineDashStyle = System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartDashStyle::Dash;
            chartArea1->Name = L"ChartArea1";
            this->chart1->ChartAreas->Add(chartArea1);
            legend1->Enabled = false;
            legend1->Name = L"Legend1";
            this->chart1->Legends->Add(legend1);
            this->chart1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 13);
            this->chart1->Name = L"chart1";
            series1->ChartArea = L"ChartArea1";
            series1->ChartType = System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::SeriesChartType::Spline;
            series1->Legend = L"Legend1";
            series1->Name = L"Series1";
            this->chart1->Series->Add(series1);
            this->chart1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(267, 242);
            this->chart1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->chart1->Text = L"chart1";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(292, 267);
            this->Controls->Add(this->chart1);
            this->Name = L"Form1";
            this->Text = L"Form1";
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->chart1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

I'll be glad for any advice.